# Iterating Search and Update cursor keeps inserting the same results for all rows

Tags: arcpy

Ive created a script to find the start XY and end XY of a polyline feature. I know I could do it manually using "Calculate Geometry", but wheres the fun in that.

At the moment, for each row, its inserting the same start and end XY and i dont know why.

```
import arcpy
fc = 'UKT Unknown Owners with Pipelines'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@"]) as scursor:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Start", "End"]) as ucursor:
        for srow in scursor:
            for urow in ucursor:
                startpt = srow[1].firstPoint
                startx = startpt.X
                starty = startpt.Y
                endpt = srow[1].lastPoint
                endx = endpt.X
                endy = endpt.Y
                startxy = "{0}, {1}".format(startx, starty)
                endxy = "{0}, {1}".format(endx, endy)
                urow[0] = startxy
                urow[1] = endxy
                ucursor.updateRow(urow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to have two cursors, you can read some fields and update other fields in a single `UpdateCursor`. Noticed you didn't use the `OID@` token anyway.

Also, you would need to check whether `Start` and `End` fields exist and are of `String` (Text) type as you are inserting strings. For instance:

```
string_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc,field_type='TEXT')]
assert all([i in string_fields for i in ['Start','End']])
```

The code for updating fields:

```
fc = r'C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\CitySaved'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@","Start","End"]) as ucursor:
    for urow in ucursor:
        startpt = urow[0].firstPoint
        startx = startpt.X
        starty = startpt.Y

        endpt = urow[0].lastPoint
        endx = endpt.X
        endy = endpt.Y

        startxy = "{0}, {1}".format(startx, starty)
        endxy = "{0}, {1}".format(endx, endy)
        urow[1] = startxy
        urow[2] = endxy
        ucursor.updateRow(urow)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that one cursor can be used for both search and update. I assume this would also apply for Insert too?

Comment: Np! Well, when you insert new rows with `InsertCursor`, you need to supply a list of tuples for each row. So, in a point fc with fields `Shape,WeekDay,Observations` you would need to supply a list of tuples where number of items matches the number of fields (excluding ObjectID as you don't need to insert any values yourself): `[ ( (45,56), 'Mon', '10'), ( (49,59), 'Wed', '20'), ... ]`. If you would like to *read* some rows before inserting, you do need to use the `SearchCursor`; when using the `InsertCursor` you only iterate your tuples to insert, not the actual `fc` attribute table.